# Are MAC ID passed via DHCP Relay

Tags: networking, router, dhcp, mac, dhcp-server

Do MAC ID pass through dhcp relay? Even if its connected on the WAN from the internet?

So if the DHCP Server is on the WAN of the router and connected to a DHCP server on the internet is it passed?

Answer (score 4):

Strictly speaking, yes. The client hardware address is a data field that will be in both the DHCPDISCOVER message (which won't leave the LAN) and the DHCPREQUEST message, which will be relayed by the relay agent.

Why do you ask?

Comment: Just curious about dhcp relay passed through the internet.

Comment: So the DHCP Server will see the MAC ID of the computer on the other end if dhcp relay is enabled on the router yes? Even if its through the internet? and not LOcal?

Comment: YES. As I said, it's in the DHCPREQUEST payload.